# How do i set an attribute in a table to have the constraint not null

Tags: sql, database, database-design, schema

I have an attribute A (which is a foreign key that references attribute A in table C) with datatype int in my table B

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE B ALTER COLUMN A int not null;
```

but it doesn't work it gives me an error

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE B MODIFY (A INT NOT NULL);
```

well but it also gives an error as well.

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The response might depend on which RDBMS you are using : oracle, mysql, ,,, ?

Comment: unexpected token "int" was found following alter column A, expected tokens "set"

Comment: There are probably some null values in the Column A. You should set values for all of them.

Comment: when i try the one with modify it says expected tokens 'foreign key"  :( and nopee no null values

Comment: Please add the errors in your question.
Also as @GMB mentioned, what is the DBMS you're using?

Answer (score 0):

First, either delete all rows that currently have NULL values in your column or update the value of that column to, for example, `0`.

After that you can continue with altering your column to NOT NULL.

I don't know your DBMS.

For Oracle, it would be:

```
ALTER TABLE B MODIFY A NUMBER NOT NULL
```

For SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE B ALTER COLUMN A INTEGER NOT NULL
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: In the comments, he mentioned that there are no null values.

Comment: If that's true then the first step is completed.

Comment: The user is getting the error, despite not having any null values.

Comment: Did he try using the syntax I recommended in my answer?

Comment: i tried and it didnt work. However, I did try ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_A (A is not null); and it worked. Is this an equal alternative?